# Importing a database into MAMP via Terminal, can't connect

Tags: mysql, svn, terminal, phpmyadmin

After frivolously attempting to import a large database (84mb) into PHPMyAdmin (tried increasing memory limit, timeout limit), I've tried importing the database via Terminal/command line, only to be denied access to the MySQL database.

I tried the method here: http://nickhardeman.com/308/export-import-large-database-using-mamp-with-terminal/

I tried the root user/password, I tried creating a new user with full db access, still no luck. Getting these errors:

```
YI:trunk mpfefferle$ /applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u [root] -p [mydbase]
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

bash-3.2# /applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u [admin] -p [mydbase]
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '[admin]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm absolutely at my wit's end. All I wanted to do was check out a working copy of the site from the SVN repos, but I need the mysql db in order to run/edit/test the site so I can update Magento so I can add new features so I can sell some lousy new products. I'm ready to give up on web development entirely. I hate it and I wish the internet would go away forever.

Comment: Are you using a default install? Also why are you using `[root]` instead of `root`? The default password for MAMP's root is empty, so try `-p` and enter nothing.

Comment: take a look to this: http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/ it's to import BIG databases with MAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID-10T Error: I didn't remove the brackets from the command I was trying to execute. `/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p mydbase` instead of `/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u [root] -p [mydbase]`